# How to bring down first-launch time?

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing, launch, activity-manager

**How to bring down launch time?** 
This App has nothing but a TextView Activity.
Thank You[image: First Image Reports huge run time than Second Image.]

[image: This run has reasonable Launch Time]

Comment: I don't get it what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @gaurav4sarma launch time on Xiaomi reports higher number - more than 10 seconds. What should be done to bring down this number to below 3 seconds. Ty!

Comment: @gaurav4sarma. I guess Red Highlited area in the Images says it clear. I am talking Performance Improvement. Ty!

Comment: Explain your reason Negative Voter!

Comment: The quality of your question is low. Firstly, you don't explain in which device are you getting the lauch time difference ? Secondly, you have not done enough research as to how to solve the issue. Please edit your question and explain the difference between the two screenshots and in when you are getting this time difference and i will remove the down vote.

Comment: @gaurav4sarma Firstly, you don't explain in which device are you getting the lauch time difference? A) ** Screen Shot Shows the Device **                        Secondly, you have not done enough research as to how to solve the issue. A) ** Its not Clear whether TraceView or Systrace works for this Situation**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems no solution right now! 
[But a work-around to cover slow load time by Android Team](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5Xu2iNHRkk)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight answer to this. As there are N number of factors that may delay app launch. So you have 2 option

1) **Create a Splash screen**. [This](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is a great tutorial on how to do it 
correctly.

2) Use [TraceView](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html) to detect what exactly is your app doing on startup which is causing this delay and then try to fix that.

Comment: app displays one single Textview. It should not take long. It suggests problem is not with the app but something External. Can you help? Ty!